# Website ignoring my SSLCertificate

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm forcing all access to my phpMyAdmin to go through HTTPS but I'm having a bit of trouble with the certificate.

I have generated a SSLCertificateFile and a SSLCertificateKeyFile and in my ssl.conf file I have referenced the locations of those two files.

The problem I'm having is the website is looking at the default SSLCertificate defined in `<VirtualHost _default_:443`>. I have defined a specific one in a `<VirtualHost *:443>` block.

My `<VirtualHost>` block in my ssl.conf file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
  ServerName www.example.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/phpmyadmin.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/phpmyadmin.key
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea why this would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two warring defaults for which certificate to use on port 443.  It can only use one (absent SNI); why do you feel it should pick yours over the default one?

Try commenting out the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` section.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried commenting out the SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile lines in the _default_ section but apache failed to start, so quickly had to uncomment them.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, as you'd then given it a section with SSLEngine On but no key or certificate data, which is unlawful.  I'm suggesting that you comment out the *whole* of the VirtualHost _default_:443 section, not just portions of it.

Comment: I decided I didn't really need to use a different SSL certificate, so I'm going with the default one. Thanks for the help.